# Overriding table alignment for linguistic glossing

Tags: tables, alignment, linguistics

A linguistics publisher wants me to switch from morpheme-by-morpheme alignment:

[image: morpheme-by-morpheme alignment]

to word-by-word alignment:

[image: word-by-word alignment]

I have been using the tabular environment for glossing. For the purposes of this question, let’s pretend I have been using two commands, `\gloss` and `\glom`. Both take two arguments and build them into a left-aligned table, with one under the other (the second under the first). The two commands differ in that `\gloss` leaves a space after the table it builds, but `\glom` gobbles the space and puts a hyphen after both its arguments. (See MWE below.)

Can I redefine these commands so that they align as the publisher wants? I probably don’t need a full solution. Knowing how to redefine `\gloss` so as to close up the space between *teuer-* and *er* (and the space between *herb-* and *tea*) will probably be enough.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\newcommand{\gloss}[2]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}#1\\#2\end{tabular} }
\newcommand{\glom}[2]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}#1-\\#2-\end{tabular}\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}

\glom{teuer}{expensive}
\gloss{er}{\textsc{m.sg.nom}}
\glom{Kr\"auter}{herb}
\gloss{tee}{tea}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are there too many glosses to reformat them to work with one of the many glossing packages (``expex``, ``linguex``, ``gb4e``, ``covington``, maybe more)?   Alternative comment: *Why would you gloss like that in the first place?*

Comment: My gripe with all glossing programs is that you can't do a search-and-replace for a single foreign-English pair. E.g., in `a b c \\ d e f`, you can't replace the pair b-e with b-g. `expex` is the only one that has version where you input pairwise (i.e., a-d, b-e, c-f), but I’ve found tabular environment to offer some further advantages—until now! This probably would have been easily fixable in `expex`.

Comment: I was just about to suggest using ``expex``'s ``nlevel`` glosses, but it seems you already knew about those. Now I am curious, what advantages do tabulars have? I cant' think of anything ``\lingset`` couldn't do.

Comment: I left it that way in my answer but beware that space in `\gloss` could cause a spurious extra white line at the end of a paragraph if it just happens to fall at the end, you should probably use `\ignorespaces` after it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\newcommand{\gloss}[2]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}#1\\#2\end{tabular} }
\newcommand{\glom}[5]{#3{#1-#4}{#2-#5}}

\begin{document}

\glom{teuer}{expensive}
\gloss{er}{\textsc{m.sg.nom}}
\glom{Kr\"auter}{herb}
\gloss{tee}{tea}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A nice facet of this solution is that it still works if you add an extra morpheme (e.g., `\glom{er}{more}` after `\glom{teuer}{expensive}`). Why I’m not a fan of most off-the-shelf example packages: see my comment on the original question. (`expex` in one of its versions is the exception.)

Comment: @DanielHarbour yes that's why I re-inserted `#3` rather than use `\gloss`